# Laravel eloquent relationship with multiple tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have 3 tables and i am making relationship of those tables but, but I'm unable to achieve it. I have 3 tables named `Books`, `Chapters` & `Hadith`. `Books` has data with a lot of chapters and `Chapters` has a lot of hadiths.

**My database structure:**

```
books
    id - integer
    name - string
    bookSlug - string

chapters
    id - integer
    chapterNumber - string
    bookSlug - string

hadith
    id - integer
    chapterId - integer (it's the chapter id)
    book - string (it's the book slug)
```

**Hadith.php - Model:**

```
class Hadith extends Model
{

    /**
     * Get the book that owns the hadith.
     */
    public function bookArray()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Books::class, 'book', 'bookSlug');
    }

    /**
     * Get the chapter that owns the hadith.
     */
    public function chapter()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Chapters::class, 'chapterId');
    }
}
```

These both relationships are woking fine if they are seperate, but as i told you that chapters table has a lot of chapters with same `chapterNumber` but the `book slug` is different.

**Example Data:**
I have 2 books:

> 1. Sahih Bukhari
> 2. Sahih Muslim

Now, I have a lot of chapters of these books like this.
[image]
[image]

**Now, in hadiths:**
[image]
[image]

See my tables.
That `chapter()` relationship function will only return the chapter of first in the table, it's only checking `chapterId`, which will not return right value, because `hadiths` is connected to both `books` and `chapters`.
The results will be like this:
[image]
The chapter `Revelation` is not belongs to `hadith of Sahih Muslim book`, it belongs to `hadith of Sahih Bukhari book`.
So, what i want to do is, first get the `book` that owns the hadith, and then get the chapter that owns book.
Can someone please help me to do this? I am stuck

Comment: you have to choose between `belongsToMany - hasOne` and `belongsToMany - belongsToMany` relations

Comment: @SuperDJ Why can't it work? Can you explain?

Comment: @SuperDJ Still, It's not working

Comment: What is Hadith in English?

Comment: You can call it blog